# Add track to playlist without login - API Spotify

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, spotify

I want to make a collaborative playlist with users on my page, but these users are not logged in to Spotify. I want the users to be able to add songs to my collaborative playlist. I have this Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: 'text',
  url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/entelperú/playlists/6sU8XOS7BLicR3COsc0Rhp/tracks/?uris=spotify:track:5eXjdTF0lp2gUgFzlKfbME',
  headers: {
    Authorization: "Bearer my token",
  },success: function (response) {
    alert(response);
  }
});
```

This returns with status `200= OK`, but never returns `201=CREATE`, so it never adds the track to the playlist. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This returns with status 200= OK, but never returns 201=CREATE, so it
>   never adds the track to the playlist. Please help me

This is because you're sending a `GET` request instead of a `POST` request. The difference is that the `GET` will [retrieve the tracks in the playlist](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-playlists-tracks/), while the `POST` [will add tracks to it](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/add-tracks-to-playlist/).

Comment: thanks my friend, this work great, Sorry, you could tell me how I get an unlimited token, the token I get from the page only is for 1 hour, thanks

Comment: An access token is only valid for 1 hour. There's however a refresh token that's valid forever, which you can retrieve using the Authorization Code oAuth 2.0 flow. Read more about it in the Authentication Guide.

Comment: Micheal is necessary the Authorization for add track into my public playlist? the playlist is mine

Comment: Yes, it's necessary for _someone_ to authenticate. But you could in theory just have an access token available that's been authorized by _your_ user, and not your application's user. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: And how i can do it in my account?